# Is there a term/word/phrase to express "only used in a specific topic"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, expressions

a comments in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3330576/656371) says

> I see no "dot product", which usually refers to vectors. This is a matrix product

which means the term "dot product" is only used for vectors, and the term "matrix product" is only used for matrices.

similarly, square foot (or square meter) is only used to describe an area rather than a distance, strength, or any other topic.

Is there a term/word/phrase to express "only used in a specific topic"?

Comment: Could you give an example of a sentence in which you'd use the word? Vectors and matrices aren't what are commonly understood as *fields*. Regardless, the word *restricted* and its synonyms are likely apposite to this matter.

Comment: @userr2684291 Vectors and matrices aren't what are commonly understood as *fields*, are they commonly understood as *topic*?

Comment: Neither. Vectors are mathematical constructs, objects, and matrices are a way to represent them (among other things).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term you are looking for is **Specifically defined**

This term can be found used in numerous articles on the internet.

My vote for the canonical name is ATA Boy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So, the whole piece could be `"dot product" is specifically defined for vectors, whilst the term "matrix product" is specifically defined for matrices`, right?